# Center TextBlock inside Grid inside Border - WPF

Tags: wpf

I am slightly confused why my TextBlock PART_HintHost is not centered vertically...

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type TextBox}"
   TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">

<!--#region Resources -->
<Style.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Er.WpfDesign;component/Themes/DefaultTheme.xaml" />
</Style.Resources>
<!--#endregion-->

<!--#region Default Values -->
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForeBrush}" />
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
<Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="pack://application:,,,/Er.WpfDesign;component/Resources/Fonts/#Roboto" />
<Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Normal" />
<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Regular" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BorderBrush}" />
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="1 1" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
<!--#endregion-->

<!--#region Template -->
<Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <!--#region Layout-->
            <Border CornerRadius="0"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                  Cursor="IBeam"/>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="PART_HintHost"
                               Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(ext:HintExt.Hint)}"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               Visibility="Hidden"
                               Cursor="IBeam"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <!--#endregion-->
            
            <!--#region Triggers-->
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource AccentBrush_1}" />
                </Trigger>

                <!--Hint Trigger-->
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}" />
                        <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="PART_HintHost" />
                </MultiTrigger>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="Text" Value="" />
                        <Condition Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                        <Condition Property="IsFocused" Value="False" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" TargetName="PART_HintHost" />
                </MultiTrigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <!--#endregion-->
            
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<!--#endregion-->
</Style>
```

As far as I am concerned, I can stack elements without any worries inside a grid, which is what I am trying to do  here. I'd expect my TextBlock to be centered vertically, just like my PART_ContentHost is:

[image: view]

I'd love to get some input as to why this does not work, open for any suggestion. Maybe a grid is the wrong approach here?

Comment: That style works fine for me after removing the `pack:` URI references. Could it be something to do with the line height on your custom font?

Comment: @RichardDeeming Oh my ducking god.... no it wasn't specifically the font, but somehow you just played rubber duck for me. I had bottom margin set for defualt style Type TextBox.......